# docker-compose up を実行するとエラー no configuration file provided: not found

Tags: docker, docker-compose

vscodeのターミナルに`docker-compose up -d`というコマンドを入力し実行すると、
`no configuration file provided: not found`というエラーが出てしまいます。
こちらの解消方法をご教授頂きたいです。
宜しくお願い致します。

状況の説明が不足しており申し訳ございません。
下記、フォルダの中身の内容で御座います。

フォルダA
●php
　・Dockerfile
　・php.ini-development
●work
　・css
　・img
　・favicon.ico
　・index.html
●docker-compose.yml
●license.txt

フォルダAの中に●と・が同じ階層という意

・Dockerfileのコード

```
FROM php:7.3-alpine

RUN apk --update add tzdata && \
    cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Tokyo /etc/localtime && \
    apk del tzdata && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN docker-php-ext-install mbstring

COPY php.ini-development /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

WORKDIR /work

CMD ["php", "-S", "0.0.0.0:8000", "-t", "/work"]
```

●docker-compose.ymlのコード

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  php:
    #build: ./php-fpm
    build: ./php
    ports:
    - 8080:8000
    volumes:
    - ./work:/work
```

dockerをインストール
WSL2をインストール
ubuntuをインストール
Linuxコマンドをwindows、vs codeで使用可能になってます

lsコマンドの実行結果

```
    ディレクトリ: D:\デスクトップ\basic_php_v3-master


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        2022/02/20     13:49                basic_php_v3-master
```

※basic_php_v3-master = フォルダ名

Answer (score 2, accepted):

docker-compose を使う際には設定ファイルとして docker-compose.yml が必要ですが、それが見つかっていないというエラーと思われます。カレントディレクトリに docker-compose.yml が存在するかを確かめてください。

`ls` コマンドの出力を見る限り、今お手元ではこのようなディレクトリ構造になっていて、

```
何かしらのフォルダ
└── basic_php_v3-master
     ├── php
     │    ├── Dockerfile
     │    └── php.ini-development
     ├── work
     │    ├── css
     │    ├── img
     │    ├── favicon.ico
     │    └── index.html
     ├── docker-compose.yml
     └── license.txt
```

本当は `basic_php_v3-master` の中で `docker-compose` コマンドを実行したかったのに、それよりひとつ上の何かしらのフォルダの中で `docker-compose` コマンドを実行しているようです。したがって `docker-compose.yml` も存在せず、エラーに繋がっていそうです。

```
何かしらのフォルダ  # ←ここで実行されてしまっていそうです
└── basic_php_v3-master  # ←本当はここで実行したいです
     ├── php
     :
```

たとえば、`basic_php_v3-master` という名前のフォルダの中に更に `basic_php_v3-master` という同じ名前のフォルダができているかもしれません。

`ls` コマンドの出力を使って、今いるディレクトリにあるファイル一覧を確認できます。この出力の中に `docker-compose.yml` が無ければ何かがおかしいので、ディレクトリを移動して確かめてみてください。

---

ところで、`ls` コマンドの出力形式を見るに、VS Code 上でお使いになっているターミナルが　WSL2 の Ubuntu ではなくて PowerShell になっていそうです。したがって実行される `docker-compose` コマンドも Linux 側にインストールされたものではなくて Windows 側にインストールされたものになる疑いがあるので、こちらも合わせてご確認ください。